# C: How to reopen the 'Standard-In' file descriptor, after having closed it?

Tags: c, stdin, file-descriptor

Is there any way of reopening or repositioning the **standard input** file descriptor at the beginning of the stream, with only the use of the following functions: `open`, `close`, `read`, `write` ?

Comment: Have you looked at `freopen()`?

Comment: Can't use dat... tbh I don't even care about reopening it I just want to reset the file descriptor to the beginning of the stream but can't use any function other than `open`, `close`, `read` & `write` :/

Comment: `close(0); open(something);` but it's unclear what you just said, once something is read in stdin, this is gone for (;ever;), if you want to be able to get it again you must save it somewhere.

Comment: Then `close(0);` to close it, and `open(pathname, O_RDONLY);`. The file descriptor returned by `open()` is the lowest not already open.  Since zero was closed, open returns zero.  But this won’t work well if the input was a pipe or socket or FIFO, and may not work with character special devices.  You need a good name for the file to be (re)opened.

Comment: @Stargateur √ Got it that's all i wanted to make sure of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler... I want to use stdin's bytes multiple times not some other file descriptors bytes.

Comment: There’s no guarantee that you can reread the bytes unless the standard input is from a regular file (and even then the guarantee is limited; other programs could also modify the file).  Almost all other file types are subject to giving different results.  I’m getting the impression there’s an XY problem here. What are you really trying to do, and why are there restrictions on what system calls you can use?